# A matrix couples two vectors, outputting a degree-two polynomial. How to transform that matrix so it acts on a projection of those vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I have an expression of the form

\begin{eqnarray}
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}
\end{array}
\right]
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
M_{11} & M_{12} & M_{13} \\       
M_{21} & M_{22} & M_{23} \\
M_{31} & M_{32} & M_{33}      \end{array}  \right]
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
x_{1}\\ x_{2}\\x_{3}
\end{array}
\right]= M_{11}x_{1}^{2}+M_{12}x_{1}x_{2}+\,...\,+M_{33}x_{3}^{2}
\end{eqnarray}

I want to make a projection of the $\textbf{x}$ vector to a vector $\textbf{y}$ in a smaller space.

\begin{eqnarray}
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
N_{11} & N_{12} &N_{13}  \\ 
N_{21} &N_{22} &N_{23}
\end{array}
\right]\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
x_{1}\\ x_{2}\\x_{3}
\end{array}
\right]=\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
y_{1}\\ y_{2}
\end{array}
\right]
\end{eqnarray}

Where the matrix $\hat{\textbf{N}}$ is fixed.

How do I transform the matrix $\hat{\textbf{M}}$ such that I get something in the same form as the first equation?

Note that I *could* automate the transformation of the polynomials and reconstruct the new coupling matrix, but this is inelegant and probably very computationally inefficient (I need to do this calculation for *much* larger matrices and many, many times).

Edit:

Note that there is no a priori relationship between $\hat{\textbf{N}}$ and $\hat{\textbf{M}}$.

The inefficient and inelegant way of doing this would be to take the polynomial

\begin{eqnarray}
M_{11}x_{1}^{2}+M_{12}x_{1}x_{2}+\,...\,+M_{33}x_{3}^{2}
\end{eqnarray}

Then take the left inverse of the second equation so that the $x$'s are given in terms of $y$'s. And then to substitute these into the polynomial, leaving an expression in terms of the $y$'s, which then could be turned back into a coupling matrix of the form

\begin{eqnarray}
Y_{11}y_{1}^{2}+(Y_{12}+Y_{21})y_{1}y_{2}+Y_{22}y_{2}^{2}=\left[
\begin{array}{c}
y_{1}, y_{2}
\end{array}
\right]
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
Y_{11} & Y_{12}  \\       
Y_{21} & Y_{22}      \end{array}  \right]
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
y_{1}\\ y_{2}
\end{array}
\right]
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. I don't understand the relation between $M$ and $N$. Maybe it'd be helpful for you to write down the inefficient algorithm which produces a correct result. Then maybe we can help optimize it.

Comment: @ZachStone Hi, thanks! I edited my post to hopefully answer your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. This is better. But there's an issue with your approach. What is 'the left inverse of the second equation'? You won't be able to solve for three variables in terms of two, so I cannot follow your instructions for this construction.

However, I have a follow up clarification question. Suppose $M$ had a factorization as $N^T UN$ for some 2x2 matrix $U$. (Note is a fairly strong assumption, as $M$ must be at most rank 2.) Then we'd have 
$$
x^TMx= (Nx)^T U Nx = y^TUy
$$

Would this solve the problem?

If so, then you have to answer some questions about when such a factorization exists. And when it doesn't exist, what information about $M$ will you have to throw out to get it? You're doing a projection, so presumably that's ok in some sense.

Do we have any assumptions about $M$? Is it real, symmetric, unitary, bounded norm, integer entries, ect? Such info may help find a computationally friendly way to factor it.

Comment: Hello again. Thanks! The matrix $M$ is real and symmetric, does that help to factor it? Also, after taking another, closer, look at my notes it's actually the "inverse" case that I have i.e. the $x$'s are linear functions of the $y$'s not the other way around, I guess this means that the transformation I need to perform is trivially easy... But it would still be really interesting to see if the factorization idea works for the original problem. Seems like something I could run into eventually.